# Concatenar pandas DataFrames unificando por Fechas

Tags: pandas

Tengo dos `DataFrames` de `pandas` con `Fechas` y `Datos`:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '16/12/2018', '18/12/2018'],
    'Datos_A': [1, 5, 9]
})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '16/12/2018', '17/12/2018', '19/12/2018'],
    'Datos_B': [7, 5, 3, 4]
})
```

Convierto las fechas al formato `datetime`.

```
df_A.Fecha = pd.to_datetime(df_A.Fecha)
df_B.Fecha = pd.to_datetime(df_B.Fecha)
```

df_A

```
    Datos_A Fecha
0   1       15/12/2018
1   5       16/12/2018
2   9       18/12/2018
```

df_B

```
    Datos_B Fecha
0   7       15/12/2018
1   5       16/12/2018
2   3       17/12/2018
3   4       19/12/2018
```

¿Cómo puedo concatenar ambas `DataFrames` de tal forma que se unifique la columna de `Fecha` para obtener el siguiente resultado?

```
         Fecha Datos_A  Datos_B
0   2018-12-15       1        7
1   2018-12-16       5        5
2   2018-12-17     NaN        3
3   2018-12-18       9      NaN
4   2018-12-19     NaN        4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el propio autor de la pregunta ha descubierto, `pd.merge()` es la solución que buscaba, si bien sólo puede operar sobre dos dataframes.

Para combinar varios dataframes, es posible repetir la misma operación entre el resultado del `pd.merge()` anterior y el siguiente dataframe.

Haciendo uso de `functools.reduce` se puede condensar la sintaxis (aunque en esencia se trata de lo mismo, hacer un `merge` entre dos, siendo uno el resultado del `merge` anterior).

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

# Definir una función que, dados dos dataframes, retorne uno
# con la combinación deseada
def juntar(left, right):
  return pd.merge(left, right, on='Fecha', how='outer')

# Defino cuatro dataframes de ejemplo
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '16/12/2018', '18/12/2018'],
    'Datos_A': [1, 5, 9]
})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '16/12/2018', '17/12/2018', '19/12/2018'],
    'Datos_B': [7, 5, 3, 4]
})
df_C = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '17/12/2018', '18/12/2018'],
    'Datos_C': [6, 15, 8]
})
df_D = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fecha': ['15/12/2018', '16/12/2018', '18/12/2018', '19/12/2018'],
    'Datos_D': [17, 15, 13, 14]
})

# Uso reduce para juntar en uno solo los cuatro, haciendo uso
# de la función juntar() antes vista. Uso "Fecha" como
# indice y ordeno el índice
reduce(juntar, [df_A, df_B, df_C, df_D]).set_index("Fecha").sort_index()
```

```
            Datos_A  Datos_B  Datos_C  Datos_D
Fecha                                         
15/12/2018      1.0      7.0      6.0     17.0
16/12/2018      5.0      5.0      NaN     15.0
17/12/2018      NaN      3.0     15.0      NaN
18/12/2018      9.0      NaN      8.0     13.0
19/12/2018      NaN      4.0      NaN     14.0
```

Comment: He marcado tu solución @abulafia como válida en vez de la mía porque resuelve mejor mi cuestión.

Comment: @PedroBiel Ah, gracias por la honestidad. Yo había votado la tuya por tomarte la molestia en explicarla.

Answer (score 1):

La [solución](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas) no era tan complicada después de todo.

```
df = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on='Fecha', how='outer')
df.sort_values(by='Fecha', inplace=True)
df[['Fecha', 'Datos_A', 'Datos_B']]

    Fecha       Datos_A Datos_B
0   2018-12-15      1.0     7.0
1   2018-12-16      5.0     5.0
3   2018-12-17      NaN     3.0
2   2018-12-18      9.0     NaN
4   2018-12-19      NaN     4.0
```

**Editado el 22.12.2018**

A petición de @shadow voy a explicar la solución.

En la primera línea de código se fusionan las dos `DataFrames` `df_A` y `df_B`, siendo `Fecha` la columna a unir e indicando en `how='outer'` que se use la unión de las `keys` de ambas `frames`. Para más información ver la documentación de [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

La segunda línea de código ordena los valores por `Fecha` y sustituye el resultado en `df`. Más info [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

La tercera línea de código muestra la nueva `df` ordenando las columnas según `Fecha`, `Datos_A` y `Datos_B`.

A posteriori me he dado cuenta que esta solución es solo válida para dos `DataFrames`. Si alguien tiene una solución mejor para más de dos `DataFrames`que no dude en exponerla.

Comment: y si a parte de mencionar que no es complicada, la explicas?

Comment: Pensaba que con el enlace ya quedaba suficientemente explicado. No tengo problema en explicar la solución, aunque no soy ningún as en la materia. Por otra parte, me he dado cuenta que esta solución solo es válida para dos `DataFrames`. ¿Alguine tiene una solución mejor para más de dos `DataFrames`?

Comment: sigue sin ser válida, todo ese código que pones por que? como funciona?

Comment: @PedroBiel Mira a ver qué te parece mi solución para varios dataframes